# ASP.NET MVC - How can I set the Default Value in a Strongly Typed TextArea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, textarea

I'm trying to make a TextArea have a default value.

```
<%: Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) model.Description, 5, 10, New With {.Value = "Description: "})%>
```

This works properly in a `TextBoxFor` but doesn't work in a `TextAreaFor`

Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the value for Description property in the controller action when creating the model, and pass that model to the View:

```
public ViewResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyPageModel() 
    {
        Description = "Description: ";
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

In the view:

```
<%: Html.TextAreaFor(model.Description) %>
```

Setting the value won't work as the contents of a TextArea are specified between the opening and closing tags, not as an attribute.

Comment: Great, this is what I was thinking too.  It's an "Add" page so the model is null.  Of course I can create an instance and pre-populate.  I'll give it a try asap.