# Default value for textarea

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a textarea element with a default value with the help of the ASP.NET MVC TextAreaFor method.

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Description, new { Class = "gray", rows = "1", cols = "1", @onclick = "clearGray($(this));", Value = "Test sentence" })%>
```

The box is there, but I don't see the value I set. It appears when inspecting, but not in the textarea. I know you're supposed to set it like `<textarea>Test sentence</textarea>`, but I don't know how to do that with the helper method.

I tried using a Content attribute, but that didn't work obviously. Any solutions?

Comment: If there is a default value for the textarea, and the textarea is bound to an entity... Shouldn't that entity have a default value?

Comment: You're probably right, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [ASP.NET MVC - How can I set the Default Value in a Strongly Typed TextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655033)

Comment: Textboxes work fine, it's the textarea that I'm having this issue with.

Comment: @Ed, how about the new link ? :)

Comment: Kind of helpful, but I couldn't make it work in my case. My entity is used for validation. I tried setting a default value, but it didn't appear. I'll go the easy way and set the default value with JavaScript on document.ready.

Comment: Never mind, works now. I was creating a default model but forgot to return it to the View.